# How can I know what entitlement items should be added for Mac sandbox app?

Tags: macos, sandbox, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

In Apple's document about App Sandbox, I found something about `Temporary Exception`, and the value of `Global Mach Service Temporary Exception` is an array, but I do know what items can this array contains.

Actually, I hope there is place where I can check what entitlement items should be added for a specific function in sandbox app. For example, for a certain function, maybe I should add some `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name` and `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write`, but the problem is what they are.

For now, when the function is unable to work in sandbox, I can find error message in system log, but still do not know what entitlements are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

documentation of sandbox is pretty inconsistent. what it suggests is to just use whatever you want to do, run the app and check console to see which functions fail. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH4-SW1

EDIT: if you're using temporary exceptions you'll need to add them in iTunes connect and explain each one in detail.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, in Apple's document, there's a note: `Note: If you request a temporary-exception entitlement, be sure to follow the guidance regarding entitlements provided on the iTunes Connect website. In particular, identify the entitlement and corresponding issue number in the App Sandbox Entitlement Usage Information section in iTunes Connect and explain why your app needs the exception.` Does this mean you should add the temporary-exception entitlement items in both your app and iTunes Connect?

Comment: @GoKu if the answer helped you, could you please mark it as accepted using the green check mark? thx :-)